# Linq lambda expression many to many table select

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I have three tables, which two of them are in many to many relationship.

Picture:

[image]

This is the data in middle mm table:

[image]

**Edit:**
Got until here, I get proper 4 rows back, but they are all the same result(I know I need 4 rows back, but there are different results)

```
    return this._mediaBugEntityDB.LotteryOffers
        .Find(lotteryOfferId).LotteryDrawDates
        .Join(this._mediaBugEntityDB.Lotteries, ldd => ldd.LotteryId, lot => lot.Id, (ldd, lot) =>
            new Lottery
            {
                Name = lot.Name,
                CreatedBy = lot.CreatedBy,
                ModifiedOn = lot.ModifiedOn
            }).AsQueryable();
```

My question is, how can I retrieve all the Lotteries via many to many table WHERE I have LotteryOfferId given only?

What I want to achieve is to get data from lottery table by LotteryDrawDateId.

First I use LotteryOfferId to get DrawDates from middle table, and by middle table I get drawDateIds to use them in LotteryDrawDate table. From that table I need to retreive Lottey table by LotteryId in LotteryDrawDate table.

I gain this by normal SQL(LotteryOffersLotteryDrawDates is middle table in DB, not seen in model):

> select
>   Name, Lotteries.CreatedBy, Lotteries.ModifiedOn, count(Lotteries.Id)
>   as TotalDrawDates from Lotteries join LotteryDrawDates on Lotteries.Id
>   = LotteryDrawDates.LotteryId join LotteryOffersLotteryDrawDates on LotteryDrawDates.Id = 
>   LotteryOffersLotteryDrawDates.LotteryDrawDate_Id
>   where LotteryOffersLotteryDrawDates.LotteryOffer_Id = 19 group by
>   Name, Lotteries.CreatedBy, Lotteries.ModifiedOn

But Linq is different story :P

I would like to do this with lambda expressions.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var query = from lo in this._mediaBugEntityDB.LotteryOffers
            where lo.lotteryOfferId == lotteryOfferId
            from ld in lo.LotteryDrawDates
            group ld by ld.Lottery into grp
            select grp.Key;
```

I do this in query syntax, because (in my opinion) it is easier to see what happens. The main point is the grouping by `Lottery`, because you get a number of `LotteryDrawDates` any of which can have the same `Lottery`.

If you want to display the counts of `LotteryDrawDates` per `Lottery` it's better to take a different approach:

```
from lot in this._mediaBugEntityDB.Lotteries.Include(x => x.LotteryDrawDates)
where lot.LotteryDrawDates
         .Any(ld => ld.LotteryDrawDates
                      .Any(lo => lo.lotteryOfferId == lotteryOfferId))
select lot
```

Now you get `Lottery` objects with their `LotteryDrawDates` collections loaded, so afterwards you can access `lottery.LotteryDrawDates.Count()` without lazy loading exceptions.

Comment: How can I use count field in this query?

Comment: this doesn't work because I am returning IQueryable with type. IQueryable<Lottery>

Comment: I think I know what you mean now, please see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

```
db.LotteryOffer.Where(lo => lo.Id == <lotteryOfferId>)
    .SelectMany(lo => lo.LotteryDrawDates)
    .Select( ldd => ldd.Lottery )
    .GroupBy( l => new { l.Name, l.CreatedBy, l.ModifiedOn } )
    .Select( g => new
    {
        g.Key.Name,
        g.Key.CreatedBy,
        g.Key.ModifiedOn,
        TotalDrawDates = g.Count()
    } );
```

Comment: Woops I only have LotteryOfferId given. I would probably have to nest selects. = Lambda Expression if possible. Thanks

Comment: Thanks bro. This works ok, now I am only trying to figure out how does GroupBy work with this many to many statement.

Comment: what do you want to group by?

Comment: As you can see in my SQL query I am having `count(Lotteries.Id)` and grouping by Lotteries.Name, Lotteries.CreatedOn, Lotteries.CreatedBy etc. I am bashing the wall whole day with this lambda, I am serious. Why is it so hard. Can't find any good lambda linq tutorial, everything is only normal linq query.

Comment: Hi thanks for additional help. I have it like this but it says that it can't convert anonymous method. http://pastebin.com/ZvUb8TSE

If I put `new Lottery()` instead of anonymous new, then I can't declare `TotalDrawDates = g.Count()`.

Comment: try enumerating the query via a `.ToArray()` call b/t `GroupBy` and `Select`

Comment: I don't exactly know what do you think. My method is like `public IQueryable<Lottery> MethodName(int lotteryOfferId)` so I have to somehow return Lottery type, but as I said if I use new Lottery I can't use g.Count

Comment: Change to `IQueryable` or create a concrete class to hold your results

Comment: It's not easy to create concrete class(viewmodel) because I use web service.

Comment: choice of return type is a topic for a new question that specifies your environment and intended use.

Comment: That's why in my answer I return the `Lottery` directly. You can't create an entity type in an entity query.

Comment: I agree with you, but how can I then achieve that I can display `count` of rows on client side in views?