# How to Return Extra Data with IQueryable method?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, breeze

I am using Entity Framework and Breeze.  For an Entity, there is a bit of associated data I would like to provide with the entity.  Getting this data is most efficiently done by querying the Entity table and joining to other tables; this query includes a group by sub-query.

I am attempting to tack this extra data on by adding it as a [NotMapped] field to the entity:

```
[NotMapped]
public string NotMappedField { get; set; }
```

So then I basically want to replace this webapi controller method

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<MyObject> MyObjects()
{
    return _contextProvider.Context.MyObjects;
}
```

With something like this:

```
public IQueryable<MyObject> MyObjectsWithExtraData()
{
   var query = from o in _contextProvider.Context.MyObjects
               // big complex query
               select new MyObject
               {
                   FieldA = o.FieldA,
                   FieldB = o.FieldB,
                   // all fields
                   NotMappedField = x.ResultFromComplexJoin
               }
   return query;
}
```

This gives me an error:

> The entity or complex type 'MyObject' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

I've tried this a few ways and it seems to fight me both from the EF side and the Breeze side.  I need to keep this as returning something like IQueryable so I can filter from the client through webapi because doing something like a ToList() here causes memory issues due to the dataset size.

So my question is - is there a best practices kind of way to accomplish what I am attempting or can anyone provide a solution?

**Update:**

I have found you can return extra data alongside of your entity and still have access to the entity as a queryable from Breeze:

```
public object MyObjectsWithExtraData()
{
    var query = from o in _contextProvider.Context.MyObjects
                // big complex query....
                select new
                {
                    theObject = MyObject,
                    NotMappedField = x.ResultFromComplexJoin
                };
    return query;
}
```

and then from the client breeze side you can do something like this:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery
           .from("MyObjectsWithExtraData")
           .where("theObject.FieldA", "Equals", 1)
           .expand("theObject.SomeNavigationalProperty")
           .orderBy("theObject.FieldB");
```

Still not exactly what I was looking for but it is actually pretty slick.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ group by on data service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476477/linq-group-by-on-data-service)

Comment: Why not just return the extra data in the HTTPResponse and then grab it after you finish querying?  Access it by passing a parameter into your .then(function (data) { console.log(data.httpResponse); }

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the EntityQuery.withParameters method.

```
// client side
var q = EntityQuery.from("CustomersStartingWith")
        .withParameters({ companyName: "C" });


// server side
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Customer> CustomersStartingWith(string companyName) {
  var custs = ContextProvider.Context.Customers.Where(c => c.CompanyName.StartsWith(companyName));
  return custs;
}
```

You can also mix and match a combination of regular query predicates with these custom parameters.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I'm not really looking to pass arguments, rather return extra data.  Maybe I could do this somehow - return new { MyOjbect, extraField } and get to it through data.results... It just seemed better to have it as an unmapped field on the Entity (it's just an extra text field)

Comment: FYI - I reworked question to hopefully ask question more clearly

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to entity can only construct pur "Data Transfert Object" : class containing only public properties with trivial getter and setter and without constructor.
See my answer to a similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21174654/3187237

**I specify my answer**

**An Entity class can't be instanciated in a LINQ to Entities query.
If you want to construct similar (or almost similar) in the query you have to define an other class.**

In your case you want to return object almost similar to your `MyObject`. So you have to define a class:

```
public class MyObjectExtended
{
    public string FieldA { get; set; }
    public string FieldB { get; set; }
    // ... all other MyObjetc fields
    public string ExtraFieldA { get; set; }
    public string ExtraFieldB { get; set; }
}
```

Now, your service can return a `IQueryable<MyObjectExtended>`:

```
public IQueryable<MyObjectExtended> MyObjectsWithExtraData() {
    var myQuery = from o in _contextProvider.Context.MyObjects
        // big complex query....
        select new MyObjectExtended {
           FieldA = o.FieldA,
           FieldB = o.FieldB,
           //... all fields ...
           ExtraFieldA = x.ResultFromComplexJoinA,
           ExtraFieldB = x.ResultFromComplexJoinB
    };
    return myQuery;
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: If the answer on another question solves this problem, then this question should be closed as a duplicate of that. Please flag the question accordingly.