# Breeze - Navigational relationship not properly assembling

Tags: entity-framework, knockout.js, breeze

I have a "Parent" entity, which has a Navigational property "Children[]."  I query the parent and its navigational properties in separate queries because I need to get some extra data about them that is more efficient on the server side, that I doing as outlined in this question: [How to Return Extra Data with IQueryable method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052403/breeze-entity-framework-how-to-return-extra-data-with-iqueryable-method) -

// server side -

```
public object MyObjectsWithExtraData() {

       var myQuery = from o in _contextProvider.Context.MyObjects

           // more query....

           select new {
             theObject = MyObject,
             NotMappedField = x.ResultFromComplexJoin
          }
       return myQuery;

    }
```

// client side -

```
var parentQuery = new breeze.EntityQuery().from("Parent").where('Id',FilterQueryOp.Equals, parentId);
manager.executeQuery(parentQuery);

var childQuery = new breeze.EntityQuery().from("MyObjectsWithExtraData").where('ParentId',FilterQueryOp.Equals, parentId);
manager.executeQuery(childQuery).then(function(data) {

  // do something with "NotMappedField"

});
```

How do I relate the Navigationals back to the Parent object? For instance, I'd like to bind the view to "Parent.Children" but after those queries run, this is an empty array - Parent().Children().length === 0.

Since breeze is not "hooking them up",  I have attempted merging them back in but I believe the entities are IN the entitymanager cache, they are just not properly related.

Comment: Breeze will automatically relate navigation properties regardless if they're queried at different times. One observation that I have is that you're executing both parentQuery and childQuery at the same time. Are you sure what you're seeing is not some race conditions?

Comment: It shouldn't matter since I am just querying by the Id though right? One query doesn't depend on the other.

Comment: That's correct. My question was more towards making sure that you're indeed checking "Parent.Children" after both queries are done. It's a bit unclear at what point you did the check from the code snippet you put here.

Comment: I just bind to both the parent and the parent.children in the view. It does relate properly (with the extra data I bring back in the separate query) if do an Expand("Children") in the main query,  but I don't think I should have to do this since I'm already retrieving in another query.

Comment: Before we go to the View, let's make sure that the ViewModel is correct first. Let's do some sanity check in your queries above. First check in your parentQuery resolved promise that when this query is done, Parent.Children is not brought to the client yet. Then execute the childQuery afterwards to show that Parent.Children is now brought to the client.